# how to split a file to list of lists TCL

Tags: tcl

I'm coding TCL and I would like to split a file into two lists of lists, 
the file contain:

```
(1,2) (3,4) (5,6)
(7,8) (9,10) (11,12)
```

and I would like to get two list
one for each line, that contain lists that each one contain to two number

for example:

```
puts $list1                 #-> {1 2} {3 4} {5 6}
puts [lindex $list1 0]      #-> 1 2
puts [lindex $list2 2]      #-> 11 12
```

I tried to use regexp and split but no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an answer already, but it can actually be done a little bit simpler (or at least without `regexp`, which is usually a good thing).

Like Donal, I'll assume this to be the text read from a file:

```
set lines "(1,2) (3,4) (5,6)\n(7,8) (9,10) (11,12)\n"
```

Clean it up a bit, removing the parentheses and any white space before and after the data:

```
% set lines [string map {( {} ) {}} [string trim $lines]]
1,2 3,4 5,6
7,8 9,10 11,12
```

One way to do it with good old-fashioned Tcl, resulting in a cluster of variables named `lineN`, where *N* is an integer 1, 2, 3...:

```
set idx 0
foreach lin [split $lines \n] {
    set res {}
    foreach li [split $lin] {
        lappend res [split $li ,]
    }
    set line[incr idx] $res
}
```

A doubly iterative structure like this (a number of lines, each having a number of pairs of numbers separated by a single comma) is easy to process using one `foreach` within the other. The variable `res` is used for storing result lines as they are assembled. At the innermost level, the pairs are split and list-appended to the result. For each completed line, a variable is created to store the result: its name consists of the string "line" and an increasing index.

As Donal says, it's not a good idea to use clusters of variables. It's much better to collect them into an array (same code, except for how the result variable is named):

```
set idx 0
foreach lin [split $lines \n] {
    set res {}
    foreach li [split $lin] {
        lappend res [split $li ,]
    }
    set line([incr idx]) $res
}
```

If you have the results in an array, you can use the `parray` utility command to list them in one fell swoop:

```
% parray line
line(1) = {1 2} {3 4} {5 6}
line(2) = {7 8} {9 10} {11 12}
```

(Note that this is printed output, not a function return value.)

You can get whole lines from this result:

```
% set line(1)
{1 2} {3 4} {5 6}
```

Or you can access pairs:

```
% lindex $line(1) 0
1 2
% lindex $line(2) 2
11 12
```

If you have the `lmap` command (or the replacement linked to below), you can simplify the solution somewhat (you don't need the `res` variable):

```
set idx 0
foreach lin [split $lines \n] {
    set line([incr idx]) [lmap li [split $lin] {
        split $li ,
    }]
}
```

Still simpler is to let the result be a nested list:

```
set lineList [lmap lin [split $lines \n] {
    lmap li [split $lin] {
        split $li ,
    }
}]
```

You can access parts of the result similar to above:

```
% lindex $lineList 0
{1 2} {3 4} {5 6}
% lindex $lineList 0 0
1 2
% lindex $lineList 1 2
11 12
```

Documentation:
[array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm),
[lmap (for Tcl 8.5)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570),
[lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm),
[parray](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/library.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Answer (score 3):

The idea of using `regexp` is good, but you'll need to do some post-processing on its output.

```
# This is what you'd read from a file
set inputdata "(1,2) (3,4) (5,6)\n(7,8) (9,10) (11,12)\n"

foreach line [split $inputdata "\n"] {
    # Skip empty lines.
    # (I often put a comment format in my data files too; this is where I'd handle it.)
    if {$line eq ""} continue

    # Parse the line.
    set bits [regexp -all -inline {\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)} $line]
    # Example results of regexp:
    #     (1,2) 1 2 (3,4) 3 4 (5,6) 5 6

    # Post-process to build the lists you really want
    set list([incr idx]) [lmap {- a b} $bits {list $a $b}]
}
```

Note that this is building up an array; long experience says that calling variables `list1`, `list2`, …, when you're building them in a loop is a bad idea, and that an array should be used, effectively giving variables like `list(1)`, `list(2)`, …, as that yields a much lower bug rate.

---

An alternate approach is to use a simpler regexp and then have `scan` parse the results. This can be more effective when the numbers aren't just digit strings.

```
foreach line [split $inputdata "\n"] {
    if {$line eq ""} continue
    set bits [regexp -all -inline {\([^()]+\)} $line]
    set list([incr idx]) [lmap substr $bits {scan $substr "(%d,%d)"}]
}
```

---

If you're not using Tcl 8.6, you won't have `lmap` yet. In that case you'd do something like this instead:

```
foreach line [split $inputdata "\n"] {
    if {$line eq ""} continue
    set bits [regexp -all -inline {\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)} $line]
    set list([incr idx]) {}
    foreach {- a b} $bits {
        lappend list($idx) [list $a b]
    }
}
```

```
foreach line [split $inputdata "\n"] {
    if {$line eq ""} continue
    set bits [regexp -all -inline {\([^()]+\)} $line]
    set list([incr idx]) {}
    foreach substr $bits {
        lappend list($idx) [scan $substr "(%d,%d)"]
        # In *very* old Tcl you'd need this:
        #    scan $substr "(%d,%d)" a b
        #    lappend list($idx) [list $a $b]
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The code works for windows :

TCL file code is :

```html
proc captureImage {} {

 #open the image config file.
 set configFile [open "C:/main/image_config.txt" r] 
 
 #To retrive the values from the config file.
 while {![eof $configFile]} {
  set part [split [gets $configFile] "="]
  set props([string trimright [lindex $part 0]]) [string trimleft [lindex $part 1]]
 }
 close $configFile 

 set time [clock format [clock seconds] -format %Y%m%d_%H%M%S]
 set date [clock format [clock seconds] -format %Y%m%d]
 
 #create the folder with the current date
 set folderPath $props(folderPath)
 append folderDate $folderPath "" $date "/"
 set FolderCreation [file mkdir $folderDate]
 while {0} {
    if { [file exists $date] == 1} {               
    }
    break
    }
 
 #camera selection to capture image.
 set camera "video"
 append cctv $camera "=" $props(cctv)
 
 #set the image resolution (XxY). 
 set resolutionX $props(resolutionX)
 set resolutionY $props(resolutionY)
 append resolution $resolutionX "x" $resolutionY
 
 #set the name to the save image
 set imagePrefix $props(imagePrefix)
 set imageFormat $props(imageFormat)
 append filename $folderDate "" $imagePrefix "_" $time "." $imageFormat
 
 set logPrefix "Image_log"
 append logFile $folderDate "" $logPrefix "" $date ".txt"
 
 
 
 #ffmpeg command to capture image in background
 exec ffmpeg -f dshow -benchmark -i $cctv -s $resolution $filename >& $logFile &
 
 after 3000
 
 }
  
}
captureImage
```

thext file code is :

```html
cctv=Integrated Webcam

resolutionX=1920
resolutionY=1080

imagePrefix=ImageCapture
imageFormat=jpg
folderPath=c:/test/

//camera=video=Integrated Webcam,Logitech HD Webcam C525
```

This code works for me me accept the code from text file were list of parameters are passed.